# Guessing the color of a point in the unit square by looking at the colors of its neighbors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, machine-learning, coloring

Let's look at the unit square, and color some of its points red and the others blue.

Now we sample n points from some distribution on the square, and guess the color of a new point using the colors of the points of the sample. We do this in two ways:

First way: we guess the color of the point using the color of the nearest point to it on the sample.

Second way: we guess the color of the point using a majority vote between the 2k+1 points from the sample that are nearest to it.

> Conjecture: the expected accuracy of the second method is at most $\frac 1 8$ more than the accuracy of the first method.

We are free to choose the coloring, n and k. The largest difference in the accuracy I found is the following:

We color $\frac 1 4 $ of the square red and the rest blue very uniformly, so that the red and blue mix very well, and choose k large, n=2k+1. Then the first method has mistake rate $0.25 \times 0.75+0.75 \times 0.25=37.5$, since with probability $\frac 1 4 $ a point will be red and will be wrong $0.75$ of the time, since the distance is independent of the coloring (so the closest point has random color). The second method will have a mistake rate of $0.25$, since we always predict the more prevalent color.

The constant $0.25$ was chosen so it optimizes this kind of attempt. Is there a better one?

Comment: Does it count if we use just four points, one red in the center of an equilateral triangle of blue ones? Then the nearest neighbour always gets it wrong, while 3 nearest neighbours gets it right 3/4 of the time.

Comment: The points are not ours to choose, they are sampled using the distribution. Moreover we look at the predictions at all points sampled, not just the center of the triangle in your example (so the first method is actually pretty good)

Comment: So the nearest neighbour can be the actual same point, if it happens to be in the sample we drew?

Comment: There are two similar ways to formulate the question. In the first we classify every point using all others except itself, but the other that is perhaps more natural is that after sampling we ask what is the expected accuracy of our decision on a new point using neighbors from the sample. In this case the probability that the point is in the sample is zero. I edited the question to reflect the second formulation since it may be easier.

Comment: I don't understand your toy problem, and I have a PhD in machine learning..

Comment: @ user1952009 I'm looking for an example of a distribution where 1-NN is considerably worse than k-NN. It is easy if we fix the training set, but in general if we only choose the function (and it is deterministic) we try to find an example where provably k-NN is as better as possible than k-NN. If n is very large and the function (here, the coloring) is fixed then I think 1-NN converges to the function (in general it is at most twice the Bayes classifier in the limit), so I should look for examples with small n.